# no qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.string' available error in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting no qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.string' available error in spring, NoSuchBeanDefinitionException in the following code. I have Test.java like the following, where I am trying to read the value from application.yaml.

```
@Configuration
public class Test {

    @Value("${value}")
    private String val;
    
    @Bean
    public Vehicle getVehicle() {
    return new Vehicle(val);
    }
}
```

In Vehicle.java

```
@AllArgConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Vehicle {

private String model;

}
```

I have another class, Driver.java, from where I have to inject Vehicle object through constructor.

```
@Service
public class Driver {

private Vehicle v;

@Autowired
public Driver(Vehicle v) {
  this.v = v;
}
```

application.yaml looks like this.

```
value: FORTUNE
price: 10000
```

Comment: Could you add your application.yml?

Comment: So I just recreated this and it's working complety fine for me. Are you sure you don't have  other annotations (e.g. Component, Service) above Vehicle?

Comment: No error if I can try above, can you check if you have shared everything which is required to raise this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a different way to inject this:

You don't need to create a configuration class where you inject the property as field and then create a bean of Vehicle. You can use constructor injection in Vehicle and make Vehicle a Component with `@Component` annotation;

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
public class Vehicle {
    private String model;
    
    public Vehicle(@Value("${value}") String model) {
        this.model = model
    }
}
```

I personally prefer this way and I hope it works for you!